# Is there an orderpreserving bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R-\{0\}$?

Tags: order-theory, real-numbers

Looking at $(\mathbb R,<)$ where $<$ denotes the usual order I understand that $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ will inherit an order (as every subset of $\mathbb R$).

I could not find essential differences so expect this to have the same ordertype as $(\mathbb R,<)$.

- Question1: Am I correct in this?
- Question2: If so, then is there a more or less obvious way to construct an order-preserving bijection?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: $\langle\Bbb R,<\rangle$ is a complete linear order; $\langle\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},<\rangle$ is not, since $(\leftarrow,0)$ is bounded above but has no least upper bound. Use this to show that there can be no such bijection.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my mind on this. Would I have been correct if $\mathbb R$ was switched for $\mathbb Q$? Of course that is another question, but maybe you have an answer allready.

Comment: @Vera: You’re very welcome. Yes, with $\Bbb Q$ you’d be right: any countably infinite dense linear order without endpoints is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. The proof uses a [back-and-forth argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method#Application_to_densely_ordered_sets).

Comment: @Vera: My pleasure!